# jQuery dataTables - Requested unknown parameter 'field1' for row 0

Tags: datatables, node-mysql

I fell kind of bad after checking all other SO question on this matter and not being able to solve it, but here we go.
When I populate my `datatable` with a simple `$.ajax` call it's fine, now I want to do it using `sAjaxSource` in the `oTable` definition and I'm facing a problem.

This is the JSON coming from a `MySQL` call.

```js
[
  [
    {
      "field1": "Relation A",
      "field2": 6378,
      "field3": 3.97,
      "field4": 16.76
    },
    {
      "field1": "Relation B",
      "field2": 131626,
      "field3": 6.49,
      "field4": 11.1
    }
  ],
  {
    "fieldCount": 0,
    "affectedRows": 0,
    "insertId": 0,
    "serverStatus": 34,
    "warningCount": 0,
    "message": "",
    "protocol41": true,
    "changedRows": 0
  }
]
```

I set `sAjaxDataProp` to `''` so it won't look for `aaData` but still no luck. 
So, is there any property I can play with in the `oTable` definition to make this JSON work?
If not, how should I take care of that JSON?
Let me know if you need to take a look at the full `oTable` definition. Thank you.

**oTable**

```js
var oTable = $("#table").dataTable({                                           
        'bServerSide': true,
        'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "startDate", "value": startDate });
            aoData.push({ "name": "endDate", "value": endDate });
        },
        'sAjaxSource':  '/getData',
        'sAjaxDataProp': '',       
        "aoColumns": [                              
            { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "field1", "mDataProp": "field1" },
        { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "field2", "mDataProp": "field2"},
        { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "field3", "mDataProp": "field3"},
        { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "field4", "mDataProp": "field4",
                        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {                                               
                                    return data + ' %';
                            } 
                    }
        ]
});
```

**EDIT**

The `JSON` I'm posting is the result of a `CALL StoredProcedure` from a `MySQL` db using the `node-mysql` module. Maybe this has occured to someone before and knows how to treat that data in order to `DataTables` to make it work.

Comment: I'd like to see the table definition please.

Comment: @markpsmith just added it! I'm still working on yesterdays table, so it's basically what we discussed. You were right! I had to make it a `get`, but now I'm stucked here so I wasn't able to check what you originally suggested on that other question. (hopefully after this I'll get that to work too!) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but you've got a typo on the first line of aoColumns: ` { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "field1", "mDataProp": "field1" }.` see fullstop at the end - should be a comma

Comment: typo during the copy/paste, corrected in the question.

Comment: What happens if you remove the sAjaxDataProp line completely?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` It happened before, after some research I realized `sAjaxSource` waits for `aaData` as the data header. So I read some post from Allan suggesting the `sAjaxDataProp` property.

Comment: I just read that post, it says that `sAjaxDataProp` is used when your data is just an array. I never use sAjaxDataProp but then I'm always returning json from the server. I don't think I can solve your problem unfortunately.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot for your effort though Mark.